# Send Email With A Filter Range Pasted Into Email Body using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have to send an email that includes a table, in the body, that was copied from a filter table.

The filter table's name is "ds" in this code.

I use function RangetoHTML (code below) but it only copies the format, not the contents of the table:

```
Sub Email_Syndicate()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim EmailSubject As String
Dim EmailSendTo As String
Dim MailBody As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim Signature As String
Dim ds As Range

Set rng = Range(Range("B2"), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each cell In rng
rw = cell.Row
If cell.Value <> "" Then
EmailSendTo = cell.Value
Nme = cell.Offset(0, 3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
xCC = cell.Offset(0, 1)
att = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
EmailSubject = cell.Offset(0, 2)
lr1 = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet3.Range("A1:N" & lr1).AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=Sheet4.Range("F2").Value
    lr = Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ds = Sheet3.Range("A1:N" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)
With OutMail
.Display
End With
Signature = OutMail.HTMLBody
'On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.Subject = EmailSubject
.To = EmailSendTo
.CC = xCC
'.Body = MailBody
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(ds) 
.Display
.send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
MailBody = ""
End If
With Application
    .EnableEvents = 1
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing: Set OutApp = Nothing

Next
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, TempWB As Workbook, TempFile As String

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    TempWB.Close 0
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing: Set fso = Nothing: Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

How can I copy a filter table containing full content to the email body?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SendEmail_1() 

Dim outlook As Object
Dim newEmail As Object
Dim xInp As Object
Dim pgEdit As Object
Dim pos As Integer

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail= outlook.Createitem(o)

'construction email
With newEmail
        .Recipients.Add ("person@email.com") 
        .Subject = "Subject goes here"
        Set xInp = newEmail.GetInspector 'gets you into the test editor
        Set pgEdit = xInp.WordEditor 'returns a word document object you can edit
        'selects data we want to copy into email
        Sheets("your Sheet").Range("your Range").Copy
        'pastes the excel range over the indicator
        pgEdit.Range(Start:=0, End:=1).PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine
        Application.CutCopyMode = True
        .display
        .send
        End With
End Sub
```